# Ruby .store function changes hash values from array to single value

Tags: arrays, ruby, store

I am trying to create a hash where keys are number, and values is array [0,0] of counts from two arrays.
what i am confused is why `my_hash2.store(x,my_hash2[x][1]+1)` don't update my counts.

```
my_hash2 = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = [0,0]}
[12,12,13,14,15,16].each do |x|
    my_hash2[x][0] += 1
end
puts my_hash2 # => {12=>[2, 0], 13=>[1, 0], 14=>[1, 0], 15=>[1, 0], 16=>[1, 0]}
[12,12,13].each do |x|
    my_hash2.store(x,my_hash2[x][1]+1)
end
puts my_hash2 # => {12=>1, 13=>1, 14=>[1, 0], 15=>[1, 0], 16=>[1, 0]}
puts my_hash2[12][0] #=> 1
puts my_hash2[12][1] #=> 0
```

Comment: When `x` equals `12` and `my_hash2` equals `{12=>[2, 0], 13=>[1, 0], 14=>[1, 0], 15=>[1, 0], 16=>[1, 0]}`, `my_hash2.store(x,my_hash2[x][1]+1)`--which is conventionally written `my_hash2[x] = my_hash2[x][1]+1`--causes the value of `my_hash2`, for the key `12` to be changed from `[2, 0]` to `my_hash2[12][1]+1`, which equals `0 + 1 #=> 1`. This explains why you are getting the undesired result.

Comment: I'm guessing you may may want `{12=>[2, 0], 13=>[1, 0], 14=>[1, 0], 15=>[1, 0], 16=>[1, 0]}.transform_values { |v1,v2| [v1+1, v2+1] } #=> {12=>[3, 1], 13=>[2, 1], 14=>[2, 1], 15=>[2, 1], 16=>[2, 1]}`. See [Hash#transform_values](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values).

Comment: You could replace your first 4 lines with `[12,12,13,14,15,16].tally.transform_values { |n| [n,0] } #{12=>[2, 0], 13=>[1, 0], 14=>[1, 0], 15=>[1, 0], 16=>[1, 0]}`. The intermediate calculation is `[12,12,13,14,15,16].tally #=> {12=>2, 13=>1, 14=>1, 15=>1, 16=>1}`. See [Enumerable#tally](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-tally), which made its debut in Ruby v2.7.0.

Comment: thank you @CarySwoveland for your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.store` associates the value given by value with the key given by key.
(as per docs https://apidock.com/ruby/Hash/store)

So this means that any value stored by your key is replaced by the new value.

```
my_hash2 = Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = [0,0]}
[12,12,13,14,15,16].each do |x|
    my_hash2[x][0] += 1
end
puts my_hash2 # => {12=>[2, 0], 13=>[1, 0], 14=>[1, 0], 15=>[1, 0], 16=>[1, 0]}
[12,12,13].each do |x|
    # in the first run in case of 12 this replaces your [2, 0] with 1 because current value of my_hash2[12][1] is 0 and 0 + 1 is 1
    # in the second run we also get 12 but my_hash2[12] is 1 now. and 1[1] equals 0. You are here essentially doing my_hash[12] = 1[1] + 1 = 0 + 1 and it correctly gives you 1
    # in the third run it operates on my_hash2[13][1] but same rules apply
    my_hash2.store(x,my_hash2[x][1]+1)
end
puts my_hash2 # => {12=>1, 13=>1, 14=>[1, 0], 15=>[1, 0], 16=>[1, 0]}
puts my_hash2[12] #=> 1
puts my_hash2[12][0] #=> 1
puts my_hash2[12][1] #=> 0
```

so you need to either not use `.store` or change this line:

```
my_hash2.store(x,my_hash2[x][1]+1)
```

to:

```
new_val = [my_hash[x][0], my_hash[x][1]+1]
my_hash2.store(x, new_val)
```

the curious thing is why doing something like `1[0]` will give you `1` but `1[1]` will give you `0` (and not raise any errors)

and the answer is again in the docs :)

https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Integer.html#method-i-5B-5D

> int[n] → 0, 1
>
> Bit Reference—Returns the nth bit in the binary representation of int,
> where int[0] is the least significant bit.

this means that if we turn 1 into bit representation we then proceed to get the nth bit from that representation. And 1 has the bit on the 0 position and all other positions (so 1,2,3,4...) are all 0. That's why 1[0] gives you 1 but 1[1] or 1[3] will get you 0.